# How can I put two pictures exactly above each other without line or space?

Tags: graphics

How can I put two pictures exactly above each other without line or space. I added picture example below, this picture is composed of two images (the header image and the smartphone image)

[image]
I Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An image inserted with `\includegraphics` is just like a big letter. You can achieve your aim by removing the interline glue that TeX inserts.

Interacting with paragraphs might be complicated, so it's better to resort to lower level commands, in this case:

```
\newcommand{\twoobjects}[2]{%
  \leavevmode\vbox{\hbox{#1}\nointerlineskip\hbox{#2}}%
}
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\twoobjects}[2]{%
  \leavevmode\vbox{\hbox{#1}\nointerlineskip\hbox{#2}}%
}

\begin{document}

\twoobjects
  {\includegraphics[trim=5 5 5 5,clip,width=.2\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
  {\includegraphics[trim=5 5 5 5,clip,width=.2\textwidth]{example-image-b}}

\end{document}
```

The `trim=5 5 5 5,clip` part is just for removing the border in the example images provided by the `mwe` package and make clearer that no vertical space is inserted. You don't need it unless there is a border you want to remove (adjust the amount of trimming).

[image]

Nothing prevents you from using `\twoobjects` in a `figure environment, for instance, as

```
\begin{figure}
\centering

\twoobjects
  {\includegraphics[trim=5 5 5 5,clip,width=.2\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
  {\includegraphics[trim=5 5 5 5,clip,width=.2\textwidth]{example-image-b}}

\caption{Whatever}
\end{figure}
```

Actually one *can* do it with LaTeX tools only, at the cost of efficiency.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\twoobjects}[2]{%
  \leavevmode\vbox{\hbox{#1}\nointerlineskip\hbox{#2}}%
}
\newcommand{\TWOOBJECTS}[2]{%
  {\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}%
   \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}c@{}}#1\\#2\end{tabular}}%
}

\begin{document}

\twoobjects
  {\includegraphics[trim=5 5 5 5,clip,width=.2\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
  {\includegraphics[trim=5 5 5 5,clip,width=.2\textwidth]{example-image-b}}
\TWOOBJECTS
  {\includegraphics[trim=5 5 5 5,clip,width=.2\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
  {\includegraphics[trim=5 5 5 5,clip,width=.2\textwidth]{example-image-b}}

\end{document}
```

You can check that the output is the same. One can consider the `tabular` approach advantageous, because the `[b]` option can be changed into `[c]` or `[t]`:

```
\newcommand{\TWOOBJECTS}[3][c]{%
  {\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}%
   \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}c@{}}#2\\#3\end{tabular}}%
}
```

and the calls

```
\TWOOBJECTS
  {\includegraphics[trim=5 5 5 5,clip,width=.2\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
  {\includegraphics[trim=5 5 5 5,clip,width=.2\textwidth]{example-image-b}}
\TWOOBJECTS[t]
  {\includegraphics[trim=5 5 5 5,clip,width=.2\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
  {\includegraphics[trim=5 5 5 5,clip,width=.2\textwidth]{example-image-b}}
\TWOOBJECTS[b]
  {\includegraphics[trim=5 5 5 5,clip,width=.2\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
  {\includegraphics[trim=5 5 5 5,clip,width=.2\textwidth]{example-image-b}}
```

would yield center, top and bottom alignment respectively. The approach with TeX primitives is equivalent to the `[b]` option.

Decide if you want to trade efficiency with flexibility.

Comment: thanks it works but how can I put a caption to the newcommand in this case?

Comment: @ocean You put the command in a `figure` environment and the caption in the usual way. I added an example.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Certainly not! Unfortunately, LaTeX doesn't provide similar features, so in this case lower level commands are necessary.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: `\mbox` is `\leavevmode\hbox`. The reason you should `\mbox` in LaTeX documents is that without the `\leavevmode` the `\hbox` will be taken as a whole line and be vertically stacked with the following text line.

Answer (score 3):

The `0pt` optional argument can be changed, even to a negative number if an overlap is desired.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,graphicx}
\begin{document}
\stackon[0pt]{\includegraphics[width=3in]{example-image-A}}%
             {\includegraphics[width=3in]{example-image-B}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`\includegraphics` does not add  any space so if `\parskip` and `\lineskip` is zero, all you need is a blank line:

```
\includegraphics{a}

\includegraphics{b}
```

Comment: And `\lineskip`?

Comment: I see no fix, though. The standard value of `\lineskip` and `\parskip` is *not* zero.

Comment: @egreg but I didn't say it was `{\setlength\lineskip{0pt}...` would work for example.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change (the default) `\parskip` as David Carlisle suggested you can use `\vspace` with a negative value to position your graphics.

```
\includegraphics{header}

\vspace{-2mm}

\includegraphics{smartphone}
```

Comment: I may be mistaken but I believe the default `\parskip` (in a standard class) *is* zero (plus 1pt glue IIRC) :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to align things vertically is to use a tabular.  You can also force them to be vertically aligned by restricting the available space using \parbox or a minipage. In both case there will still be a small gap which can be removed by tweaking.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe}

\newlength{\desired}
\setlength{\desired}{2in}

\begin{document}

\noindent\hfil%
\fbox{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
\includegraphics[width=\desired]{example-image-a}\\[-4pt]
\includegraphics[width=\desired]{example-image-b}
\end{tabular}}%
\hfil%
\fbox{\parbox{\desired}{%
\includegraphics[width=\desired]{example-image-a}\vspace{-1.5pt}
\includegraphics[width=\desired]{example-image-b}
}}

\end{document}
```

[image: aligned images]

Answer (score 0):

It might be overkill, but you can do this with `tikz` if you use two nodes places one on the other without separation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} [inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
    \node (A) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{example-image-a}};
    \node [anchor=north] at (A.south) {\includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{example-image-b}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]